# How to create Alarm on CPUUtilization Metric for multiple instances at a time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 20 EC2 Linux instances and trying to create alarms if threshold is met. If I have to create alarms for CPU metric of every instance from the Cloud Watch console, I have to create 20 alarms. Instead of doing that,I want to create alarm on CPUUtilization Metric for multiple instances at a time ?:

Comment: Would you want the alarm to trigger when _one_ instance exceeds a certain threshold, or when an aggregate (eg SUM or AVERAGE) of _all instances_ exceeds the threshold? Can you tell us more about your use-case?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of alternatives:

- Build the alarms into the CloudFormation template for your instances and then every instance can easily have its own alarm.
- If you have detailed metrics turned on for your instances (at an additional cost), you can get CloudWatch to aggregate statistics such as average CPU utilisation. See [Aggregate Statistics Across Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/GetSingleMetricAllDimensions.html) for the procedure.

Comment: Thanks craigcaulfield for reply, I tried using these way but couldn't get result.
Do you have any script or process to achieve this ?

Comment: The link above points to some detailed steps to implement the aggregate statistics method if you're happy with the additional costs of detailed statistics. Otherwise, have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/use-cloudformation-template-to-create-cloudwatch-alarms.html#use-cloudformation-template-to-create-cloudwatch-alarms-example which shows how to add CloudWatch alarms into a CloudFormation template.